# Asp.net Response.Redirect on Azure

Tags: asp.net, redirect, azure

I have a website that has a couple of buttons on a main page (Index.aspx)
When any of these buttons are clicked they add some parameters to a url and the website redirects to another page.

```
   Response.Redirect("~/Charges/blabla.aspx?BillId=" + rcEmployee.SelectedValue);
```

This works fine on my local machine and Windows server environments, but when I deploy it on an Azure webrole it does not do the redirect.

When the browser is on http://someurl.cloudapp.net/ and click the button it stays on the page (and using fiddler it shows a file/page not found page)
but if i click on the button when the url is http://someurl.cloudapp.net/index.aspx the button works normally...

Can anyone explain why this is happening? and how can this issue be fixed?

Thanks

Comment: Any chance you can point us to the website so we can see what's going on?

Comment: What does the text of the "File not found" page say?

Comment: Can't do that smarx, as its an internal site

Comment: 404 The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

I am yet to encounter this kind of problem but in the meantime you can try MapPath ans see if it works

```
Response.Redirect(HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath("~/Charges/blabla.aspx?BillId=" + rcEmployee.SelectedValue));
```